# how can i convert string value which has bot numeric and alphabet to whole number(integer)

Tags: javascript, output

I would like to convert string value to integer or whole number , when ever i try it pick up only integer value.can anyone tell me how to convert strings value to whole number or integer.

```js
var strings = "123abc";
var convt = parseInt(strings);
console.log(convt);
```

I have got only 123.please anyone explain will be appreciated.

Comment: what output do you want out of `123abc`?

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to do is only parse the string as a number when the full string represents a real, whole number, you can use the Number function. For example:

```js
var strings = "123abc";
var convt = Number(strings);
convt = isNaN(convt) ? null : convt
console.log(convt);
```

If what you mean is that you want to convert the letters into their ASCII numerical representation, this would do the trick:

```js
var strings = "123abc";
var newString = "";

for (let i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    newString += /[\d.-]/.test(strings[i]) ? strings[i] : strings[i].charCodeAt(0);
}

var convt = Number(newString);
convt = isNaN(convt) ? null : convt
console.log(convt);
```

Comment: thank you very much, i am very gladful for your help.